# How to delete the other object from figure by using opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv

> I tried to detect the yellow lines in the following picture but the logo(yellow color) will be marked as well. My question is that how to mask the logo?

[image]

I use the standard code of the Hough Transform. My code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('Road3.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


low_yellow=np.array([18, 94, 140])
up_yellow=np.array([48, 255, 255])
 mask=cv2.inRange(hsv, low_yellow, up_yellow)
 edges = cv2.Canny(mask,75,150)

 lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,50,maxLineGap=250)
  for line in lines:
 x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
 cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),5)

 cv2.imshow('image', img)
 cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
 k = cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I would approach this by thresholding on yellow. Then get the contours and filter them on contour dimensions, keeping only the ones that are long and thin. Draw those contours as white on a black background as a mask. Then do your hough line transform if you need to get the start and end points from the mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multi-scale template matching approach.

You want to remove the following image:

[image]

- 1. Detect the image

  ```
  import cv2
  import imutils
  import numpy as np

  template = cv2.imread("template/template.jpg")
  template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
  (h, w) = template.shape[:2]

  image = cv2.imread('nnEGw.jpg')
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  found = None

  for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
       resized = imutils.resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
       r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

       if resized.shape[0] < h or resized.shape[1] < w:
           break

       edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
       result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
       (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

       if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
           found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

  (_, maxLoc, r) = found
  (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
  (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + w) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + h) * r))

  cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
  cv2.imwrite("result/edges2.png", image)
  ```

  [image]

  - 2. Fill the rectangle

  ```
  cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (255, 255, 255), -1)
  ```

  [image]

  - 3. Apply Hough Transform

  ```
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

  low_yellow = np.array([18, 94, 140])
  up_yellow = np.array([48, 255, 255])
  mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_yellow, up_yellow)
  edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 75, 150)

  lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, maxLineGap=250)
  for line in lines:
      x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
      cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)

      # cv2.imshow('image', img)
      cv2.imwrite("result/edges3.png", edges)
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is your 'template/template.jpg'?

Comment: The wheelchair image. I placed the image in template folder and renamed as template.jpg